# java - split a string in two parts by a property

Tags: java, string, split

**How can I split a string in two parts, without a delimiter, but where the first part is a group that fulfills a certain predicate, and the second part is the rest (without a loop)?**

I want to get the hang of handling string manipulation in Java and write a simple program that transforms a word to a simplified piglatin version of it.

So the ruleset for this would be

- if a word starts with a consonant group, take this group put it on the end of the word and add a "ay", e.g. `dog -> ogday`
- if not, add "way" to the end of this word, e.g. `egg -> eggway`

But where there are various examples of "split a string on a delimiter" to be found on the internet - I found none that "conserved" the delimiter.

In my favorite language haskell I would use `takeWhile` or a small parser written with the Parsec-library (Parser combinators). But as I am new to java I looked at the documentation of String, Scanner, Pattern (though this is still a bit a mystery to me) but I didn't find a proper solution.

I know I can use a simple for loop to do this, but I rather have a library that handles string manipulation/parsing. Which library would that be? Or do I have to wait for Java8 and all the nice fold/lambda stuff.

### EDIT - more examples

- `Oxford -> Oxfordway` as it starts with a vowel
- `cyberpank -> erpankcybay` as it starts with a
- `prank -> ankpray`
- I don't distinguish silent consonants

Comment: What was the problem with Pattern/Matcher? Seems like you could use a regex for the first rule and then if that doesn't match simply append 'way'

Comment: can i transform the string with a regex? - As I said regexes I still don't understand regexes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this

- first case `s = s.replaceAll("^([qwrtpsdfghklzxcvbnm])(.+)", "$2$1ay")`
- second case `s = s.replaceAll("^([eyuioa].+)", "$1way");`

Comment: It did not work quite correct but gave me the necessary - hint - corrected your solution to fit my case